# Uniqueness of model of curve over DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

I understood that properness of $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$ tells us that for a fixed field $K$, a curve $C$ over $K$ and a DVR $V$ with fraction field $K$, there is a unique curve over $V$ with generic fibre $C$.

However, I have the feeling that there is some choice in smoothening a node. For example for $n \neq 0$, the generic fibre of (the completion of) $Spec(V[x,y]/(xy-\pi^n))$, where $\pi$ is a uniformizing parameter, will always be $\mathbb{P}^1_K$, but these curves are non-isomorphic as curves over $V$, as the rings $V[x,y]/(xy-\pi^n)$ are non-isomorphic for different $n$, which would mean that $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ has different lifts to $V$, which would contradict properness.

Could someone point out to me where the mistake in my argumentation is?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this kind of technical stuff, but the stacky version of properness involves allowing for base-changing along a finite branched cover of the base scheme $\operatorname{Spec}V$ (i.e. passing to a finite extension of $K$). I'm quite tired at the moment and can't see how to put the argument together, but the ``standard" smoothing $xy - \pi$ and the others which you bring up are related by just such a base-change.